# Instagram api permission review (only got basic and public_content)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have submitted my application to `Instagram` and they only approved basic and `public_content` while we asked for all the other permissions and they got declined, but I'm not able to understand their reason for example this is their feedback for 'Likes' permission:

> This permission (likes) is only granted to apps that enable brands and advertisers to manage their communities. We do not grant access to apps that do not fall into these categories. Please review our documentation (https://www.instagram.com/developer/review) for more information

What is meant by manage their communities? This permission is only allow you to either Like or Unlike media post.

Anyone could help us understand their mean?.

Comment: what does your app do?

Comment: Our application provides management and monitoring functionality.

Comment: then explain that clearly in your description, and make sure your video screencast shows that functionality, if your app is publicly accessable (free app) by anyone then u may not get POST api permissions, if u add a paywall for your app, then you are more likely to get permission

Comment: I'm pretty sure that we showed the likes functionality in the screencast, and yes it's free app. I'm wondering why they will not approve it for this reason while there is some free apps with full permissions ex: websta.me Also they didn't approve the 'follower_list' which is not POST request. Btw, how we will resubmit our application and be able to demo for them the unapproved features as we miss the needed permissions?

Comment: @krisrak any thoughts on my last comment? Thanks.

Comment: sandbox mode allows POST for sandbox users, so u can show demo with that, my app https://www.picodash.com had to be a paid app to get all permissions, they did not want to give all permissions if it was free, atleast u got `public_content`, i got only basic initially.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120069/discussion-between-alex-mansour-and-krisrak).